# SHP 2016 Copy a list to to another List using PS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell

The below PowerShell I was able to copy all items from a list to another list but I am missing the metadata in the destination list.
How to keep the Metadata when copying the list. Please help.

#Get Objects
$WebURL = "http://"

$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL

$SourceListName = ""

$TargetListName= ""

$SourceList = $web.Lists[$SourceListName]

$TargetList = $web.Lists[$TargetListName]

#Get all source items
$SourceColumns = $sourceList.Fields

$SourceItems = $SourceList.GetItems();

#Iterate through each item and add to target list

Foreach($SourceItem in $SourceItems)
{
$TargetItem = $TargetList.AddItem()

```
Foreach($column in $SourceColumns) 
{
  if($column.ReadOnlyField -eq $False -and $column.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
 {
  $TargetItem[$($column.InternalName)] = $sourceItem[$($column.InternalName)];
  }
```

$TargetItem.Update();

}

Answer (score 1):

We suggest you use "**Save as Template**" feature to meet your needs.

1.Go to **List settings** of the source site >> **Save list as template**

[image]

2.On the Save as Template page, please select "**Include Content**" option.

[image]

3.Go to **Site settings** of the source site >> **List templates**, you will see the list template you just created.

[image]

4.If you want create list in same site, please following steps:

- a.Go to **Site Content** >> **add an app** >> find and click the list template and create new list

[image]

- b.Go to the new list, you will find all items are copied to the new list.

[image]

5.If you want create list in another site, please following steps:

- a.Download the template of the source site

[image]

- b.Upload the template on the destination site

[image]

- c.Go to **Site Content** of the destination site >> **add an app** >> find and click the list template and create new list

[image]

- d.Go to the new list, you will find all items are copied to the new list.

[image]

========================= **Updated Answer** =======================

1.Both lists should have same columns

[image]

2.Please run the below PowerShell script as an admin

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
#Configuration variables
$WebURL = "http://sp/sites/sitename/"
$SourceListName = "listnameA"
$TargetListName= "listnameB"
#Get Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$SourceList = $web.Lists[$SourceListName]
$TargetList = $web.Lists[$TargetListName]
#Get all source items
$SourceColumns = $sourceList.Fields
$SourceItems = $SourceList.GetItems();
#Iterate through each item and add to target list
Foreach($SourceItem in $SourceItems)
{
    $TargetItem = $TargetList.AddItem()
    Foreach($column in $SourceColumns) 
    {
        if($column.ReadOnlyField -eq $False -and $column.InternalName -ne "Attachments")
        {
             $TargetItem[$($column.InternalName)] = $sourceItem[$($column.InternalName)];
        }
    }
   $TargetItem.Update();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not a solution since the list is very big I have to use PowerShell.

Comment: Hi Eric. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: I did create the new list from Template. The PowerShell script will copy all data and metadata except "created" and "created by" not correct, so created column will show today's date for all records.

Comment: Hi Eric. This is normal. Because using PowerShell to copy items to another list is equivalent to creating new items in the new list, so "Created" and "Created By" will be different with old list.

Answer (score 0):

The before mentioned script, which can be seen on the [sharepointdiary](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/copy-list-items-between-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell.html) worked for me.

There is a big Important Notice at the start of the article.
"Both lists should have same columns! So, have the source list saved as template and create a new list from it".
Have you checked that all internal column names are the Same?

You could use @EchoDu_MSFT answer to replicate the list and leave out the list items and move over the list items to the new list, afterwards